# Large difference between algebraic and numerical eigenvector system

Tags: eigenvalues

I'm working on a general procedure where I need to obtain the eigen-decomposition of a matrix. I noticed the following funny difference, though. When I use

```
A = {{0, 0, -(I/10000), 1/5760000000, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, -(I/10000), 0, 1/5760000000, 0}, 
 {-((7I)/250000), -((7 I)/250000), 0, 0, 0, 1/  16000000000}, 
 {150632/125, 11232/125, 0, 0,   0, -((7 I)/250000)}, 
 {11232/125, 150632/125, 0, 0, 0, -((7 I)/250000)}, 
 {0, 0, 1000, -(I/10000), -(I/10000), 0}}
{eval,evec}=Eigensystem[A]
```

I obtain a nice right eigenvector system with zeroes and real OR imaginary values on each column (I'm outputting the transpose of `evec`):
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \frac{733 i}{802944000} & \frac{1}{96000 \sqrt{697}} & \frac{733 i}{802944000} & -\frac{1}{96000 \sqrt{697}} & \frac{i}{12304000} & \frac{i}{12304000} \\
 -\frac{i}{22304000} & -\frac{1}{96000 \sqrt{697}} & -\frac{i}{22304000} & \frac{1}{96000 \sqrt{697}} & \frac{i}{12304000} & \frac{i}{12304000} \\
 -\frac{1}{192000 \sqrt{697}} & 0 & \frac{1}{192000 \sqrt{697}} & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{33}}{24608000} & \frac{\sqrt{33}}{24608000} \\
 -\frac{769 i}{12 \sqrt{697}} & -1 & \frac{769 i}{12 \sqrt{697}} & -1 & -\frac{1}{769} \left(36 i \sqrt{33}\right) & \frac{36 i \sqrt{33}}{769} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{769} \left(36 i \sqrt{33}\right) & \frac{36 i \sqrt{33}}{769} \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, if I run

```
{eval,evec}=Eigensystem[N[A]]
```

I obtain the following output

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -\text{1.2043417539000936$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{7.688193188799198$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} i & \text{1.8531222222424326$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{8.212513455384941$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} i & \text{3.3413281903381244$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{4.423526477148793$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24} i & -\text{3.3413281903381207$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{2.930323256407006$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24} i & -\text{7.743377801175729$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24}+\text{7.596590615921973$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & \text{1.9865788552372406$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}+\text{7.596590615921986$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i \\
 \text{3.5233965561984676$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}+\text{3.7759202564356767$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} i & -\text{3.37554746682975$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}+\text{4.033430892140163$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} i & \text{3.4515872267481366$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8}-\text{2.3326479805751402$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24} i & -\text{3.451587226748133$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8}+\text{2.374275106979798$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25} i & \text{2.6645278093098886$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24}+\text{7.596590615921924$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & -\text{3.0443234191254495$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24}+\text{7.596590615921939$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i \\
 -\text{1.6614525879086802$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}-\text{5.270427857833774$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & \text{1.7747605189685852$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}-\text{3.4599580883513965$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & -\text{1.3028961283509568$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}-\text{8.378138931700507$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & \text{7.456547295202199$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-24}-\text{8.378138931700512$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i & -\text{2.1819545346633222$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{2.4980389433541498$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23} i & \text{2.1819545346633222$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}-\text{1.4102245048664485$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23} i \\
 -0.274879-0.0204425 i & -0.449739+0.0218367 i & 0.895109\, +0. i & 0.895109\, +0. i & -\text{1.0760380728691062$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-18}-0.251361 i & \text{1.1271449376910601$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17}+0.251361 i \\
 0.923353\, +0. i & 0.875453\, +0. i & 0.135738\, -\text{4.836881707484031$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17} i & 0.135738\, -\text{2.5946706042721974$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17} i & -\text{8.770004331448554$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17}-0.251361 i & \text{1.3097277227809595$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16}+0.251361 i \\
 -0.00842181-0.267155 i & -0.00899616+0.175383 i & -\text{4.0179138893596894$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17}-0.424683 i & -\text{6.433703220485387$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-18}+0.424683 i & 0.934685\, +0. i & 0.934685\, +0. i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The eigenvalues in each case are remarkably similar in magnitude, and in fact they really only differ in the sense that the second case has minimal non-zero imaginary parts... In the first case:
$$ \left\{-\frac{\sqrt{697}}{60000},-\frac{\sqrt{697}}{60000},\frac{\sqrt{697}}{60000},\frac{\sqrt{697}}{60000},-\frac{\sqrt{33}}{20000},\frac{\sqrt{33}}{20000}\right\} $$
in the second case
$$ \{0.000440013\, -\text{1.7327019397255794$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} i,-0.000440013+\text{1.0587911840678754$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} i,0.000440013\, -\text{9.237297459711376$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23} i,-0.000440013-\text{2.4134262448873742$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} i,-0.000287228-\text{1.4321361106426905$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-20} i,0.000287228\, -\text{3.049711151506121$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-20} i\} $$

Now, I understand that Mathematica has normalized the eigenvectors to give a '1' at the bottom-most value in the algebraic case, and probably just normalized the norm in the numerical case. But I don't understand what has happened to the 0 entries? I can't spot anything in the numerical eigenvectors that is close to 0. In other words, it seems to me that theeigenvectors differ a lot from each other.

Comment: Try `{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[N[A, 30]]`.

Comment: @user64494 even if I try `{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[N[A, 150]]` and then output the result with `evec // Transpose // MatrixForm // N`, I can see that the exponents of ~10^(-170) can be ignored, but none of the entries goes to zero on both the real and imaginary components. Am I missing something from linear algebra that would allow for such a difference?

Comment: There are eigenvalues whose eigenspace has dimension >1. So the eigenbasis is not unique (even under sign flips), and different algorithms may find different eigenbases.

Comment: Right, interesting. So in the algebraic case, I do `NullSpace[A + eval[[1]] IdentityMatrix[6] ]` , and I find two vectors, so the eigenspace has dimension >1 and the basis is thus not unique, hence the difference? In the numerical case this is not the case due to round-off errors, then? Would you care to write it up as a mini answer?